# Отследить запрос перехода на сайте

Tags: алгоритм, php, javascript

Как, в зависимости от того, с какого поискового запроса зашел пользователь, выдать ему соответствующую информацию.

Допустим пользователь перешел с запроса "купить холодильник", нахожу слово холодильник, и выдаю поп-ап с акцией по холодильникам. 
Или же отследить регион.
Может кто уже задавался этим вопросом.

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']. не?

Comment: Для вебмастеров, вешающих бесполезные попапы на сайт, в аду есть отдельный котел. Отведите лучше место под акции на видном месте - меньше посетителей потеряете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Грубый** пример для гугла.

Получаем адрес, с которого перешли, нарезаем на куски, поделенные символом равно.
Т.е. пользователь пришел по ссылке

*https://www.google.kz/search?q=%24_SERVER&oq=%24_SERVER*

```
$query = explode('=',$SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
print_r($query);
```

А мы это видим прилично:

```
Array
(
    [0] => https://www.google.kz/search?q
    [1] => %24_SERVER&oq
    [2] => %24_SERVER
)
```

Ну, а потом выбираем из нашей базы текст с такой темой, например.

```
getsql('SELET * FROM table WHERE title ="'.$query[2].'"');
```

*В идеале для разбора запроса использовать регулярное выражение, которое вернет нам хост, построить ассоциативный массив из гета, а потом в зависимости от хоста (Google|Yandex|Bing|Gigpogoda|пр.) Смотря в какую переменную он пишет текст запроса, выбирать нужный нам текст.*

С регионом веселее. Как вариант смотреть IP, делать whois запрос и разбирать полученные данные. [Например так](http://scripts.pws.ru/whois/source.php)

Comment: P.S. Не дал более нормальный пример вычищающий мусор за попапы =)